# Django template won't re-load after changes

Tags: django

I'm trying to get a simple Django app working following the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/).  I have a working view, URLconf, and template.  I'm not using any packages, files, or settings not covered in the tutorial.  I'm not even using a data model yet.  I'm using Django 3.0.4, Python 3.6, and Ubuntu 18.04.

When I make changes to the template file, they don't show up when I refresh the finished web page.  I've tried clearing the browser cache and restarting the server.  There's nothing I can find on the [tutorial page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/) on templates or [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/) on templates to explain why this is happening or what I can do about it.  All of the information I can find online and on Stack Overflow about similar problems involve "static files" from a package 'django.contrib.staticfiles', which I'm not using.  I've also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704068/django-template-wont-update), which I've verified is not my problem, since I've never copied template files (there's only one in the entire project and it has never moved).  This is just the basic tutorial, slightly adapted.

What's wrong?

**Edit**: Here's the views.py file, HTML template, and requested selections from settings.py.

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

def viewFunction(request):

    template = loader.get_template('appName/message.html')
    context = {
        'message': "Hello World"
    }

    response = HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
    return response
```

**message.html template**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content" class="message">
             <p>{{ message }}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'appName.apps.AppnameConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Two questions: 1) when talking about 'template file' do you mean pure html + jinja or you mean frontend as well? 2) what command do you use to startup the server?

Comment: The template file is pure HTML with some DTL, just as in the tutorial.  I start the test server with `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Can you post one of the non-changing html's, the view that handles it and settings.py fragments installed_apps and templates?

Comment: I edited the question to add them